Почему doсker-compose не хочет видеть подключаемый топ при запуске на Windows?
Столкнулся с проблеой подключения томов на Windows. Пошерстил инет и решил реализовать
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.6
    container_name: my-db
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $PASSWORD_FOR_DOCKER
      POSTGRES_USER: $USER_FOR_DOCKER
      POSTGRES_DB: $POSTGRES_DB
    expose:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}
    volumes:
      - my_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # - ./db_config/postgres_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql 
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  my_volume:
    external: true

В итоге после запуска
docker compose --env-file .env up

Выплевывае ошибку:
external volume "my_volume" not found

Где я проколося? Почему н не видит создаваемый том my_volume?
UPD:
По комментарию исправил подключение - запустился. Но решил явно указать место тома на хосте:
volumes:
  my_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: .db
      o: bind

В итоге все запустилось, но папка db - пустая, соотвествено сохранение произошло в другом месте. Как указать нужное место для хранения файлов?

external: true означает, что том был как-то создан заранее и что компоуз не должен заниматься управлением его жизненного цикла

@user7860670, спасибо! А как указать место на хосте?
